# Javascript: How to correctly create a new custom istance from object definition (like a class)

Tags: javascript, class, prototypejs

I see that is still not possible to use `class` freely thanks to IE11.

So I would like to use `prototypes` and `object.create` in order to create my istances in the most lightwight way possible.
However I only found to go with `Object.assign()` which is a sort of merger of object not a inizializator.

```
var classDefiner = {
   x: 1,
   y: 2,
   standardFunction : function() {
       return this.x+this.y;
   }
};

var istance = Object.assign({}, classDefiner ,{
    x: 10,
    z: 3,
    customFunctionA : function() {
        return this.x+this.y+this.z;
    },
    customFunctionB : function() {
        return this.x/this.y;
    }
});
```

Honestly this sound to me just a redundant copy of all methods of `classDefiner` in `{}`.
Not a great use of `prototypes` or `class`, or `object.create()`.
Is this the right way or is there something I can improve?

PS: The Challenge is to do not declare any single function/method but use instead a `{}` wrapper for the `class` and another for the `istance` for the sake of readability. I know I can add many method manually by using `istance.newMethod` or even `newobject.prototype.newMethod`. But this is long and messy if you have tons of method to add.

Comment: *"I see that is still not possible to use class freely thanks to IE11."* Just transpile for IE11, using [Babel](https://babeljs.io) or similar.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I'm just talking to use a better lightweight way of write method for istance... use a plugin in order to cleanup the code is like 'kill yourself in order to stop listen noises'. Plugin & External Libraries should be used only when really really really needed.

Comment: Your first sentence suggests you *want* to use `class` syntax and are blocked by IE. All I did was point out that you don't need to be blocked by that. If you don't want to use `class` at all, then that opening sentence doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder you are right. All others thought are just personal opinion. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do it by *copying* the properties, what you're doing with `Object.assign` is probably as clean as it's going to get for now.  (Note that you'll have to polyfill `Object.assign` on IE11, but it's fully polyfillable.) One tweak is you can use method syntax rather than property initializer syntax for the functions:

```
var instance = Object.assign({}, classDefiner ,{
    x: 10,
    z: 3,
    customFunctionA() {                 // ***
        return this.x+this.y+this.z;
    },
    customFunctionB() {                 // ***
        return this.x/this.y;
    }
});
```

ES2018 will give us syntax that would replace `Object.assign` in the above:

```
var instance = {
    ...classDefiner,                    // ***
    x: 10,
    z: 3,
    customFunctionA() {
        return this.x+this.y+this.z;
    },
    customFunctionB() {
        return this.x/this.y;
    }
};
```

(Of course that won't work on IE11 either without transpiling. :-) ) Technically [the proposal for it](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-object-rest-spread) is only Stage 3 at the moment, but it'll probably be Stage 4 in a couple of weeks after the January TC39 meeting, and is already implemented in V8 (in Chrome) and SpiderMonkey (in Firefox).

If you want to do it with inheritance, you were on the right track with `Object.create`:

```js
var classDefiner = {
   x: 1,
   y: 2,
   standardFunction() {
       return this.x+this.y;
   }
};

var instance = Object.assign(Object.create(classDefiner), {
    x: 10,
    z: 3,
    customFunctionA() {
        return this.x+this.y+this.z;
    },
    customFunctionB() {
        return this.x/this.y;
    }
});

// Demonstrating it
console.log(instance.standardFunction());
console.log(instance.customFunctionA());
```

In terms of whether to just copy the properties or inherit, I'd say there's not a lot in it either way.

In favor of inheritance:

- If, *after* creating `instance`, you added or modified `classDefiner`, those changes would be reflected in `instance` (because it inherits rather than copying).
- There might technically be slightly less memory use inheriting instead of copying the properties, but unless you're doing millions of these, it's not something you're going to care about.

In favor of copying:

- Esp. as of the property spread notation mentioned above, the syntax is more concise. You can get close with a wrapper function, though.
- In theory, there could be the ***tiniest*** additional overhead using inherited properties vs. copied "own" properties, but I doubt anything you'd need to care about on modern JavaScript engines.

Comment: umh no. I don't need to separate the latest object.
The latest object is just a singleton and I don't need neither I want to declare it twice.

Comment: @MaxCuttins: In that case, just create it the way I create `subclassDefiner` above. I've added to the answer. (I also realized you weren't using method syntax, which makes things a bit more concise, and added that in.)

Comment: Ok, is there any real difference with my method stated in the question?
Maybe performance? Because right now i just see that my code lighter than yours: `var istance = Object.assign({}, classDefiner ,{});` instead of yours: `var istance = Object.assign(Object.create(classDefiner) ,{});`

Comment: @MaxCuttins: There's not a lot in it either way. Using inheritance, if you added to `classDefiner` later, those changes would be reflected in `instance` even if done after it's created; with just copying the properties, they wouldn't be. There might theoretically be a tiny performance hit using an inherited property vs. an "own" property, but I bet nothing measurable in modern JS engines. In theory there'd be greater memory use copying the properties rather than inheriting them, but unless you have millions of these, I wouldn't think that would be important either.

Comment: Ok. So there is no other way to write this code with wrappers? I don't know but I fell `Object.assign`is a poor way to copy the object. Probably only in my mind.

Comment: @MaxCuttins: Nothing wrong with `Object.assign` to copy the object's "own" properties, that's its raison d'être. But good news: ES2018 is likely to give us syntax for this: `var instance = {...classDefiner, x: 10, z: 3 /* etc. */};` but of course that won't work on IE11 either without transpiling. :-) Technically [the proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-object-rest-spread) is only Stage 3 at the moment, but it'll probably be Stage 4 in a couple of weeks, and is already implemented in V8 (in Chrome) and SpiderMonkey (in Firefox).

Comment: @MaxCuttins: I've revised the answer to remove the bit creating a `subclassDefiner` (since you don't want that) and show the property spread notation coming soon (already here in Chrome and Firefox), and to include a couple of thoughts on inheritance vs. copying.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you've meant this:

```
function classDefiner() {
   this.x = 1;
   this.y = 2;
};

classDefiner.prototype.standardFunction = function() {
       return this.x+this.y;
}

var a = new classDefiner();

a.standardFunction(); //3
```

Comment: I have to add more than 20 functions.
It's unreadable to declare all the methods in that way.
I'm escaping from that write of write code. This is why I asked if I can make this declaration clearly wrapping all in `{}`

Comment: As your answer is not technically wrong I have updated the question in order to match what I want to achieve with syntax lightweight.